# Tensorflow: Change placeholder during ScipyOptimizer

Tags: tensorflow, mathematical-optimization

I am using the `ScipyOptimizerInterface` in `tensorflow`. I provide a minimal example below, where I optimize function `f(x)=p*x**2+x` for some `placeholder` `p`.

Now, I would like to **gradually change the value of the placeholder during optimization**, i.e. I want to change `p` in every step of the optimizer. Because I am using `ScipyOptimizerInterface` however, I only get the final result of the optimization, not after a single step.

**Question**: How can I gradually change `p` over time? Of course, I still want the optimization to run efficiently.

---

## Motivation

In my actual use case, I want the final result of my optimization to satisfy some non-linear constraints. To ensure this, I introduce a penalty for violations of those constraints, and weight this penalty with `p`. By increasing `p` over time, I allow some violations initially, but ensure that in the end, the constraints are satisfied.

---

## Minimal example

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.opt import ScipyOptimizerInterface 

# setup variables
x=tf.get_variable("x",initializer=[1.0])
p=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
val=10.0

# setup optimization
f=p*x**2+x
optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(f, options={'maxiter': 100})

# run
with tf.Session() as session:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    session.run(init, feed_dict={p:val})
    
    optimizer.minimize(session, feed_dict={p:val})
    
    ret=session.run(x)
    print(ret)
```

---

If it matters: My tensorflow version is `1.4.1`.

Comment: (1) From scipy-perspective: this is not gonna work as the wrappers are pretty much outer-layer based and there is not much interaction possible besides getting the current solution-vector in a callback (2)From optimization-perspective:likely not gonna work as warm-/hot-start-theory for NLP-solvers is pretty limited. Even for linear-solvers, most software i know, does only support changing right-hand sides (which is more simple than what you need) although some other things are possible in theory (and maybe for some solvers) (3)Tensorflow probably just wraps the whole method->all problems apply

Comment: So the only thing i can imagine is somehow an efficient model-update which is solved from scratch using a dynamically changed initial-point. Of course this depends somewhat on the solver (Interior-point methods as an example would be pretty bad as there are some complex conditions on initial points).

Comment: @sascha: Thanks for your comments! I am unsure what you mean by (2). I agree that always starting from scratch could be an option, possibly the only one...